# Is there any way to stop the comment dialog from showing up after liking a page using the facebook like social plugin?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a website that utilizes the facebook like button social plugin. It's part of a small toolbar that also has a tweet button and other similar things. After clicking the button, however, facebook automatically displays a menu to let you add comments to the post. This really throws off the css in my site and makes things look really bad. I really just want people to be able to click the recommend button, and have it end there. I don't want any extra elements to be brought into the HTML code after the action is taken.

Does anybody know of any way to stop all the extra stuff from being displayed?

Answer (score 0):

From the FAQ at the bottom of the [like button social plugin reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/):

> **When will users have the option to add a comment to the like?**
>
> If you are using the XFBML version of the Like button, users will
>   always have the option to add a comment. If you are using the Iframe
>   version of the button, users will have the option to comments if you
>   are using the 'standard' layout with a width of at least 400 pixels.
>   If users do add a comment, the story published back to Facebook is
>   given more prominence.

So one option would be to use the iframe instead of the XFBML version, and make sure the width is less than 400px.